# Image not rendering in md format file in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, markdown

I have a directory called "features" in the root and inside this directory has image "state_transitation.JPG" and document "myMdc_features.md"

I am trying to add an image "state_transitation.JPG" to the md extension document "myMdc_features.md"  in my repository by using markdown below:

```
![alt text](./state_transitation.JPG)

![alt text](/state_transitation.JPG)

![alt text](state_transitation.JPG)

<p>
<img src="state_transitation.JPG" />
</p>
```

I tried all above options but this is giving page could not be found error. 404

Both myMdc_features.md and image file are in same path/directory.

What is the correct way to display an image in gitlab myMdc_features.md?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.0

Answer (score 2):

I think that the first option should work, assuming they are in the same folder.  I made an example repostiory [here](https://gitlab.com/brendan-demo/stack-overflow/images/-/tree/master) that works.

Source of the file:

```
 Hello World

![](./i-have-no-idea-what-im-doing.jpg)
```

Output in GitLab:
[image: Picture of the output displaying as expected]